# Converting for to while loop

Tags: python, loops, converters

Does anybody know how to covert this to a while loop ?

```
def function(number):
   dictionary_num = {}
   for i in number:
     if i in dictionary_num:
      dictionary_num[i] += 1
     else:
      dictionary_num[i] = 1
```

Comment: Why not just use a `Counter()` instead? `from collections import Counter; dictionary_num = Counter(number)`. That's it. At any rate, converting to a `while` loop will make the loop more verbose. Why do you need to do so? You'll need a separate index counter, increment it in the loop, and use `while` to loop until the counter exceeds the length of `number`...

Comment: I've never use import before, can u maybe give me an example?

Comment: Here you go: [Standard Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#standard-modules)

Comment: @RobinDun: see the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) on modules.

Comment: it is said that i need to define Counter ?

Answer (score 1):

technical answer :

```
def whloop(numbers):
    d = {}
    numbers = list(numbers)
    while numbers:
        i = numbers.pop()
        if i in d:
            d[i] += 1
        else:
            d[i] = 1
    return d
```

But there's really no point in doing so...